# Create table statement for a very large table in oracle

Tags: oracle, large-data

I am planning to store like 5 TB data in a table. Following is the default script I have generated to create the table :

```
CREATE TABLE measurements
(
 measurementtime              DATE NOT NULL,
 height number,
 offset number
)
PCTFREE    10
PCTUSED
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
TABLESPACE mytablespace
STORAGE   (
  INITIAL     262144
  NEXT
  PCTINCREASE
  MINEXTENTS  1
  MAXEXTENTS  2147483645
  FREELIST GROUPS  0
  FREELISTS  0
 )
```

Can you please tell if I need to modify any of the parameters?

Comment: At 5TB, you may want to look into having a primary key or some indexes somewhere :-)

Comment: You may want partitioning or compression. Depends on the Oracle edition and what you actually plan to do with the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult to give good advice without knowing the entire system.  The ideas below are guesses based on your script and on your previous question [How do I design a table which will store very large data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410811/how-do-i-design-a-table-which-will-store-very-large-data)   But don't believe everything you read.  You'll need to do a lot of testing.  You can easily spend many days trying to optimize a table like this.

1. PCTFREE 0: If you have 5 TB and no indexes I
   assume you won't be doing any
   updates.  If that's true, you can
   change PCTFREE to 0 and save 10% of
   your space.
2. NOLOGGING: If you don't need your data to be
   recoverable, and if your database is
   in archivelog mode, then you may
   want to add NOLOGGING.  NOLOGGING
   with APPEND inserts will not
   generate redo.  (This may be
   unnecessary if your tablespace is
   already set to NOLOGGING.)
3. PARALLEL: You'll definitely want to use
   parallelism with this table.  Since
   this table is likely unusual for
   your system, it's probably better to
   define parallelism at the statment
   or session level.  But if you won't
   have control over all of the
   statements run against this table
   you may want to consider definining
   the degree here to make sure that
   statements don't run in serial.
4. Remove unknown options: I think you should remove all of the
   options that you didn't specifically
   set, or don't understand.  If you
   used a tool like TOAD or
   DBMS_METADATA to generate the script
   they will always list every option,
   but usually you should leave most of
   that stuff out and let Oracle use
   whatever it likes.
5. Compression/Partitioning: Like Gary mentioned, partitioning
   may be very useful.  But in your
   previous question you mentioned
   storing up to 200TB and only 5 TB
   per day.  Are you using a poor man's
   partitioning; re-naming and
   recreating the table every day?  If
   this is just a day's worth of data
   then compression should be very
   helpful with measurementtime.
6. Block size: I'm not sure what the settings of
   "mytablespace" are, but since you
   didn't mention anything about it I'm
   guessing you're using the standard
   block size.  It *might* be worth
   using a large block size for this
   table so you can get even better
   compression (since compression is
   done per block, the more data in a
   block the more Oracle can compress).
   I'm relucant to suggest this,
   because 99% of the time when people
   change the block size it doesn't do
   what they think it should.  But with
   such a large amount of data it might
   be worth considering.